# C# I have a function that takes a byte argument, how do I define the byte?

Tags: c#

I don't know how to define or call if this is even the correct wording a byte to execute a function that requires a byte to be returned to run the function.

My function:

```
    /// <param name="sourceFileName">The filename of the source file. Presumed to exist.</param>
    /// <param name="destinationFileName">The filename of the target file. Will be overwritten.</param>
    /// <param name="key">The key to encrypt with</param>
    /// <param name="mode">The mode of encryption. Use Engine.* constants.</param>
    /// <param name="blockSize">The chosen block size.</param>
    public static void StartEncryption(String sourceFileName, String destinationFileName, String key, byte mode, int blockSize = 16)
    {
        if (mode != ECB && mode != CBC && mode != CFB && mode != OFB)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid block cipher mode of operation.");
        }
    }
```

This function resides in a class file and I would like to run the function from a separate csharp file aka my Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** Starting Encryption ***");
        Engine.StartEncryption("test.txt", "", "12345", ?BYTE ECB?, 16);
    }
}
```

Now where I have ?BYTE ECB? is the byte I would like to call but I don't know how to syntax it to call the ECB byte.

Comment: Do you want a literal value?  What value do you want?

Comment: Use [`System.Byte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx)

Comment: How about `Engine.ECB` ("...Use Engine.* constants")

Answer (score 1):

I should have read the comments...
/// The mode of encryption. Use Engine.* constants.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("*** Starting Encryption ***");
        Engine.StartEncryption("test.txt", "", "12345", Engine.ECB, 16);
    }
}
```

I needed to add the class "Engine" in front of the ECB since that is where the byte resides. Sorry all.